# C# public abstract method to create and get derived Instances

Tags: c#, inheritance, static-methods, abstract

I know, I've read and know, that static abstracts don't exist. Still I'd like to know how I can savely implement the Idea of getting all Instances that derive from an abstract class. I know I can write a Helper Method, but I'd rather want to create an abstract class that has a static abstract method every abstract subclass has to implement personally. to only have one Set of derivedInstances.

Here's what I came up with...

```
public abstract class _ScriptableAbstract : ScriptableObject
{
    protected static _ScriptableAbstract[] DerivedInstances;

    public static abstract _ScriptableAbstract[] GetDerivedInstances();
}
```

And the Class implementing that would be

```
public abstract class _EmergeAnimation : _ScriptableAbstract
{
    protected GameObject gameObject;

    public abstract void Setup(GameObject gameObject);
    public abstract IEnumerator Execute();

    public static _EmergeAnimation[] GetDerivedInstances()
    {
        if (DerivedInstances == null)
        {
            DerivedInstances = Instances created with Activator/ScriptableObject and Reflection.
        }
        return DerivedInstances;
    }
}
```

So for me it would be best to use Generic methods with the _ScriptableAbstract class so I can make use of this static abstract.

Well that's the best I can explain. It's late and I'm tired. Verbalizing everything makes it more complicated. Actually I'm happy that I program with my belly and not my head^^

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieve some sort of animation by having a base class implement one "state" and then each inherited class provides yet another state, so that if you start from the base class and call the method on all the inherited classes, it performs an animation?

If so, then nested inheritance isn't the way to go. It's just not intended for that purpose. Inheritance *allows* classes to override what their base class does. It can't *force* them to override anything or ensure that each class will implement a method differently. Even an abstract class can only require inherited classes to implement a method. Once it's implemented you can't force inherited classes to override it.

If you want 5, 10, or 20 classes that each inherit from an abstract class, you could just write those classes to directly inherit from that class. They don't need to inherit from *each other*, like this:

```
public abstract class MyBase{}
public class Inherited : MyBase{}
public class Inherited2 : Inherited {}
public class Inherited3 : Inherited2 {}
```

etc. There just wouldn't be any benefit. But you could do this:

```
public abstract class MyBase {}
public class Inherited : MyBase {}
public class Inherited2 : MyBase {}
public class Inherited3 : MyBase {}
```

And then have a collection like this:

```
var steps = new List<MyBase>();
steps.Add(new Inherited());
steps.Add(new Inherited2());
steps.Add(new Inherited3());
```

Then instead of trying to walk through the classes and subclasses, you just iterate through the items in the collection and call the same method on each one. Each one can implement the abstract method differently.

You might even find that you can use an interface instead of an abstract class.

That's just an oversimplified example. But you can see for yourself how as soon as you try to use nested inheritance the problem gets messy fast. That happens even in simpler scenarios. If inheritance gets messy it's good to step back and question why you're using it.